# JQPlot ( view plot image ) breaks in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, jqplot

For some reason jqplot can't render images in firefox.

It just crashes on line 182 of the image script with no plausible problem I can see.

When I run the exact same function in chrome it works perfectly.

Never had this problem before.

I recently switched to OSX, think it might have something to do with firefox on this os.

If anyone knows of a solution please let me know.

I will post an update if I figure it out myself.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is likely with this piece of code in writeWrappedText() function:

```
for (var i=0; i<wl; i++) {
    w += words[i];
    if (context.measureText(w).width > tagwidth) {
        breaks.push(i);
        w = '';
        i--;
    }  
}
```

Commenting out i-- solves the issue for me.

Comment: Great find. I was experiencing the exact same as OP and this seems to be the only solution online that actually fixes it.

Comment: While this may work, the creators of jqplot opted to fix this problem with the code listed in @augray 's post and simply uploading the most recent version should fix this issue for anyone up against the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was discovered and fixed last year by the jqplot team in [this bug report](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issues/983/infinite-loop-in-chrome-using). [The fix](https://bitbucket.org/ef4/jqplot/commits/a59e7e7a5e97ea721a7b8571612b334e8c025b36) they recommend is to change:

```
if (context.measureText(w).width > tagwidth) {
```

to

```
if (context.measureText(w).width > tagwidth && w.length > words[i].length) {
```

Looks like the fix should be in recent versions of jqplot. If you run into this, updating your library may help.

Answer (score 0):

I render images from graphs without any problem...

```
    var imgData = $('#chart').jqplotToImageStr({});
```

Then I send to a php page the imgData var (that contains the base64 image) to let it be downloaded directly.
I you want just to show that image, you just have to add that var to the src attr of a image tag (or opening it as a popup passing the var as the href attr of the window)

```
    window.open(imgData,"_blank","scrollbars=0");
```

Comment: the problem is that the .jqplotToImageStr() function causes the browser to crash. Can't get imgData var.

Comment: I think it's not jqplotToImageStr function that cause the browser to crash but smoething else in your code,  did you try to check what is last page or piece of code the browser tries to run (press F12)? What's the exact error it gives?

Comment: I have tried to implement it in my site and i have also tested all of the example files. As soon as you call the toImageStr function the browser crashes. Could be something like firebug or web developer tools plugin that could be causing this issue. Here is the error: Warning unresponsive script.  A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: http://localhost/jqplot/src/jqplot.toImage.js:182

Comment: Don't know why it crashes, try this instead: https://github.com/lsiden/export-jqplot-to-png/blob/master/sample-usage.html