# Chrome hanging when applying jqplot code that converts chart to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jqplot

I have tested my code on two browsers so far (Chrome and Firefox). The code works perfectly fine in Firefox, but it hangs (Oh, Snap) in Chrome. I have isolated the offending code to these lines

```
var imgData1 = jQuery('#graph1').jqplotToImageStr({});
var imgData2 = jQuery('#graph2').jqplotToImageStr({});
var imgData3 = jQuery('#graph3').jqplotToImageStr({});
var imgData4 = jQuery('#graph4').jqplotToImageStr({});

var imgElem1 = jQuery('<img/>').attr('src', imgData1);
var imgElem2 = jQuery('<img/>').attr('src', imgData2);
var imgElem3 = jQuery('<img/>').attr('src', imgData3);
var imgElem4 = jQuery('<img/>').attr('src', imgData4);

jQuery('#imgChart1').append(imgElem1);
jQuery('#imgChart2').append(imgElem2);
jQuery('#imgChart3').append(imgElem3);
jQuery('#imgChart4').append(imgElem4);
```

I suspect the issue is with `jqplotToImageStr({});`.

Unfortunately, no errors get thrown, so I have nothing to provide in terms of that. Googling shows this to be a known problem, but no fix has been offered as far as I can see, so I am turning here for answers.

So far I have tried to updated both the jqplot library and ensuring jQuery is up-to-date, but the issue remains.

**UPDATE:** I've discovered that it works fine in Chrome when my host is my local host (127.0.0.1:8000) but not from the live server.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836075/jqplot-view-plot-image-breaks-in-firefox). The best answer, IMO, is the one by @augray. The most recent version of jqplot has the fix listed there and once I uploaded the newest jqplot to the server properly, it worked on Chrome, which is a great relief.